# Why weren't the Uchihas brought back with the Edo Tensei?

Tags: naruto

Why didn't Kabuto bring back the entire Uchiha clan? It was one of the four noble clans of Konohagakure, and was also reputed to be the village's most powerful clan, producing shinobi that were exceptionally talented and battle-oriented. -[Naruto wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uchiha_Clan)

Sasuke and Obito were still alive and only Itachi and Madara were brought back. I don't see a reason why Kabuto did not bring back the entire clan. I know these four are exceptionally strong, but there were other promising member like [Shisui Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shisui_Uchiha).

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edo Tensei needs the DNA of the person to be reincarnated. (Chapter 520)

[image: Edo Tensei needs DNA]

Kabuto could not bring back the Uchiha clan because he could not get their DNA.

Danzo, who commissioned the Uchiha clan massacre, must have had their bodies thoroughly destroyed to prevent enemies from misusing the Sharingan. Given Danzo's character and principles, we can be certain he would take such measures. For instance, he was very upset on knowing that Kirigakure's Ao had taken Konoha's Byakugan.

Kakashi also makes a mention of this rule in Chapter 16.

[image: Kakashi telling about hunter-nins]

Madara's death was independent of the Uchiha Clan massacre, and Konoha thought he was dead anyway, so the possibility of Danzo destroying his body does not arise at all.

After Madara's death, Tobi must have taken great efforts to make his body inaccessible, because otherwise it would ruin the plan of him falsely assuming Madara's identity. However, he probably did not destroy it completely, and Kabuto (or Orochimaru) may have found the body or its parts somehow. Tobi was understandably shocked when Kabuto showed him the Edo Tensei Madara in the sixth coffin, since it meant his plan was ruined.

Itachi's dead body was easier to obtain, since he died just a few weeks before in his own hideout.

Comment: But doesn't Tobi/Obito have a room filled with Sharingan, which contain Uchiha DNA.

Comment: It was with Obito and he would have never given it to Kabuto, because his aim was *Project Tsuki no Me* and he knew that Kabuto already had an edge with the re-incarnated Madara. Why would he aid his own enemy even though they were fighting together?

Comment: Yes, exactly as @R.J says. Obito was forced into the alliance, and he did not trust Kabuto even then. Kabuto was bound to interfere with the Moon's Eye Plan. The sharingans were for Tobi's use, and giving them to Kabuto is like saying, "Here, take my gun and shoot me." :)

Comment: i am a little unsure of the time line here... did Madara die after the Uchiha clan massacre or before. If you have some source to confirm your point please could you update it in your answer. @Happy

Comment: @debal You are right, I made an assumption there. Anyway, my point is that Madara's death wasn't part of the Uchiha massacre, so Danzo couldn't destroy his body. I will update the answer with this.

Comment: Wow, you pay attention to detail. That scene with Kakashi happened so long back, I doubt anyone would have remembered it!

Comment: *take my gun and shoot me*.=) +1

Answer (score -2):

I think the uchiha would have brought great strength in battle...how ever sauske would not have the courage to kill his fellow clans men it's better than the gedo statue,but sauske did not plan on turning on obito at the time so it would have been a "just in case plan"

Comment: Do you have any sources at all to back this statement up?